# AJAX Form being submitted twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit, double-submit-problem

Hi I have the following Js code.

The problem is somehow the form is being submitted twice, however, only one instance of it being submitted is showing up on the safari inspector showing the requests....

And it's definitely not an issue with the server side request as I have tested that to check. so It's definitely something client-side.

```
$('#replyForm').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var userID = $('#replyForm #userID').val();
    var content = $('#replyForm #content').val();

    if(content != '')
    {

        var ajaxURL = BASE_URL + 'ajax/sendMessage/';

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 
                userID: userID,
                content: content
            },
            success: function(){

                updateConversation();

            }
        });

        $('#replyForm #content').val('');

    }
    else
    {

        alert('Cannot send an empty message');

    }

    return false;

});
```

Comment: `however, only one instance of it being submitted is showing up on the inspector` - which inspector? If you are talking about a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug or Chrome Developer toolbar and you are seeing a single request then I guarantee you that a single request is sent and that the problem you are *observing* is coming from somewhere else :-)

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, Safari inspector, showing ajax calls, so only seeing that single request going out, yet there are two made as two entries are made in the db

Comment: The fact that there are 2 entries in your database doesn't imply that there are 2 AJAX calls. Maybe there's a bug in your server side call. Any chance to show it?

Comment: Thing is it must be the jQuery, or something, as this is making a call to an API that is also used by an android app and it doesn't have a duplication problem so can't be the api

Comment: the serverside call is fine as i mentioned an android app connects to the same api that does the server side with no problem, i can also made a call to the api via my terminal and it only makes one insert i think it may have something to do with the browser opening connection to the file before sending the real request but im stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok After doing a lot of testing from every angle, I have found out it was server side code doing this! not running the request.

I was using curl to form my requests to the API. and I was running curl_exec twice, once to check on the success and then again to get the result of the call.

This is what was causing the duplication.

Hope this helps some who are having similar issues.